# How to get the default value of an optional parameter

Tags: php, function, optional-parameters

Probably this is a limitation of PHP, but is it possible somehow, to call a function - and enforcing the 'default' value of an optional parameter - even if in the function call, the optional parameter is given (and == `null`)?

Maybe it's easier to show what I mean:

```
<?php
    function funcWithOptParam($param1, $param2 = 'optional') {
        print_r('param2: ' . $param2);
    }

    funcWithOptParam('something'); // this is the behaviour I want to reproduce

    // this will result in 'param2: optional'

    funcWithOptParam('something', null); // i want $param2 to be 'optional', not null

    // this will result in 'param2: ' instead of 'param2: optional'
?>
```

Now, the easiest answer to this is "dont write `null` then" - but in my special case, I get a parameter `array` for a `function` call, and only can do this:

```
<?php
    funcWithOptParam($param[0], $param[1]);
?>
```

So even if `$param[1]` is `null`, the `null` will overwrite the default value of the optional parameter

I only see one solution to this - to skip the optional parameters, and do it like this:

```
<?php
    function funcWithOptParam($something, $notOptional) {
         if($notOptional === null) {
              $notOptional = 'defaultvalue';
         }

         ...
    }
?>
```

But I would like to know if there's another solution to this. Is there a 'real' `null` value in PHP? That really translates into 'nothing'? Something like `undefined` in js?

Comment: A _Hacky_ solution would be to `preg_match` the source code to find the default value. Doubt it will work for arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not pass the whole array as the function argument?
You simply call it this way:

```
funcWithOptParams($params);
```

And handle it like so:

```
function funcWithOptParams($params) {
     if(!isset($params[1])) {
          $params[1] = 'defaultvalue';
     }

     ...
}
```

This approach gives you the possibility to pass only the arguments you want to specify and have default values in the ones you don't want to specify. As a bonus you don't have to worry about the order of the arguments.

Comment: Great answer, I was looking for a more elegant way of calling a function with a lot of (partly optional) params. This way, I do not have to bother with calling the function with the same defaults in the right order as defined in the function. Thnx for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [func_num_args](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php) & [func_get_args](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) to create the behavior you want

```
function funcWithArbitraryNumParams(){
  $args = array();
  if(!empty(func_num_args)){
   $args = func_get_args();
  }

  print_r($args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the default value, but it's rather ugly...

```
$function = new ReflectionFunction('your_function_name');

foreach ($function->getParameters() as $param) {
    echo 'Name: ' . $param->getName() . PHP_EOL;
    if ($param->isOptional()) {
        echo 'Default value: ' . $param->getDefaultValue() . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/xFQKQRzN).

You could check if the arguments are `NULL`, and if so, replace them with the default value.